# Can meditation help students in exams?

Tags: science, meditation-practicalities

Came across this interesting research paper: [Harvard Unveils MRI Study Proving Meditation Literally Rebuilds The Brain’s Gray Matter In 8 Weeks](http://www.feelguide.com/2014/11/19/harvard-unveils-mri-study-proving-meditation-literally-rebuilds-the-brains-gray-matter-in-8-weeks/)

If above is the case, is there any research showing that meditation makes better students or make people fair well at exams? Does it boost your IQ / EQ?

Comment: Perhaps related: [stackexchange.com/questions/...](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/82/does-studying-mathematics-or-science-lead-to-a-practitioner-of-buddhism-acquirin/114)

Answer (score 3):

Here are references to some studies on this.  I don't know how rigorous they are!

An abstract of a study:
http://pss.sagepub.com/content/early/2013/03/27/0956797612459659.abstract

Two articles in the Huffington Post that reference studies.  I imagine trying to google the universities and professors involved might get you some abstracts or summaries of results:

http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/04/20/meditation-better-grades_n_3053719.html

http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/03/27/mindfulness-testing-focus-reading-comprehension_n_2957146.html